# Hibernate setMaxResults paging

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria

If I don't set `setFirstResult(-)` and recursively call `criteria.setmaxresults(10)` each time, will it automatically grab the next 10 items from the database?

Comment: so confirm need to use setFirstResult(offset) to do paging?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.  You have to use `criteria.setFirstResult(0)` and page through yourself, something like this:

```
public List getCarters(final int firstResult, final int maxResults) {

    final Criteria criteria = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
                      .createCriteria(SomePersistentClass.class);
                      .add(Restrictions.eq("name", "Carter"))
    criteria.setFirstResult(firstResult);
    criteria.setMaxResults(maxResults);

    return criteria.list();
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to use a Long for max results?

Answer (score 2):

Of course, no. Criteria grabs data from database only when you call .list() or .uniqueResult()

Comment: yes, of course return with .list()..     so if i call the same method with setmaxresult(10), it will not auto grab the next 10 items? must use setfirstresult(offset) ?

Comment: If you want next 10 items, you should use setFirstResult(offset) and setMaxResults(10).